# Node.js app - different NODE_ENV when launched by NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a *node.js* app. It runs in the "production" mode when it was launched by the `npm start` and in the 'development' mode when it was launched by `node start.js`. I don't understand the difference.

How can I set the 'development' mode according the system variable also for the 'npm start'?

Inside the script I log the value of the NODE_ENV this way:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

My system variable:

```
d:\>echo %NODE_ENV%
development
```

My NPN content:

```
...
"private": true,
"main": "start.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --use_strict start.js",
...
```

The problem:

- when I run `node --use_strict start.js` - returns: "development" (right)
- when I run `npm start` - returns *production*  (wrong)

(win: 7, npm: 3.8.3, node: v5.10.1)

Comment: What does running `npm config get production` from the command line get you?

Comment: Thanks. It helps. The answer is 'true'. I have changed that by the `npm config set...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
npm config set production=false
```

The NPM provides own config register.

Hre is an info: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config